# Post content in wp_remote_post

Tags: api, wp-remote-post

I'm trying to post content with wp_remote_post. Content that I want to be posted is in a separate php file, which echo's block with html and WPBakery shortcode.
I tried *include* but it didn't work, I tried *file_get_contents* but it posts 1 in the content as if there were no errors executing the code.

Code that I use:

```
            $postDataContent = "blahblahblah";

            $api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://SITE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password )
            ),
            'body' => array(
                'title'   => $title,
                'status'  => 'draft',
                'content' => $postDataContent,
                'categories' => 6,
                'date' => $published,
                'slug' => $id
            )
        ) );

            $body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );
```

The question is about 'content' => "$postDataContent". If I declare $postDataContent = "blahblahblah"; it will post "blahblahblah" on created pages. But instead I need it to post content of the separate php file. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

EDIT

> Can you include your attempt? It's difficult too debug code that
> hasn't been shared

This is the main part of the code I'm concerned about:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://WEBSITE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'LOGIN:PASSWORD' )
    ),
    'body' => array(
            'title'   => 'My test',
        'status'  => 'draft', // ok, we do not want to publish it immediately
        'content' => 'lalala',
        'categories' => 5, // category ID
        'date' => '2021-05-05T10:00:00', // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
        'slug' => 'new-test-post' // part of the URL usually    )
) );

$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );
```

It works fine. LOGIN:PASSWORD uses pair from application passwords. It creates a new post with specified title, slug, category. But what I want to do is to post different content into 'content'. So, instead of 'lalala' it will be getting content from another php file. That file has some php and html in it. My thoughts: create a variable and assign to that variable another php file. I tried:

```
ob_start();
include "fileWithContent.php";
$postDataContent = ob_get_clean();
```

But it doesn't work.

> include

doesn't work either.

Maybe there is another way to create a post in WordPress and add content from the separate php file?

Comment: `"$postDataContent"` is just a complicated way of doing `$postDataContent`, you don't need to wrap it in quotes if it's just the one variable. I noticed that your code is incomplete and does not contain the part where `$postDataContent` gets its value, can you fix that using the edit link to update your question? It's important. Also, look into using application passwords

Comment: Hey Tom. I updated the start post. The variables $title, $published, $id just have some related data and are totally fine. I'm using application passwords, thanks. The $username and $password are taking data from there. $postDataContent needs to include in itself php page with php code, html, and wpbakery shortcode. I put "blahblahblah" just as an example. The code also works, but I can't manage to make it work with $postDataContent having data from a whole php page.

Comment: Can you include your attempt? It's difficult too debug code that hasn't been shared

Comment: Ok, I edited the start post and added only the working part of the code I'm concerned about.

Comment: have you tested this without the REST API call and looking directly at the variable? Your use of output buffers appears to be correct though I can't rule out that it's being cleared via other methods in-between as it's all out of order. What is inside `fileGetContents.php`? I'd much rather you modified your code to the smallest simplest version that reproduces the issue instead of concealing parts of your code and asking us to just trust the problem isn't there and doing a lengthy back and forth to ask questions, the likelihood the problem is in the code you shared is very low